# ASP.NET HttpPost method. can't receive data properly

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

There's the project, that has Node class declared

```
public class Node
{
    public string id { get; set; }
    public int group { get; set; }

    public Node( string id, int group)
    {
        this.id = id;
        this.group = group;
    }

    public Node()
    {
    }
}
```

And method, that has to receive this object and do stuff with it

```
[HttpPost]
public IActionResult Create(Node node)
{
    //does stuff here
    return NoContent();
}
```

One thing I can't understand is how my JSON object has to look like to be correctly deserialized in this method. I mean I tried to send JSON that looked like this: {  "id": "TEST",  "group": 1} but thing received object with id = null, group = 0. I don't get it, what do I do wrong?

Comment: what version of asp.net are you using? Is this .net framework or .net core?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default, the action method model binding in ASP.net is looking for `application/x-www-url-formencoded` encoded form values.

You are POSTing JSON in the body of your request, so you need to use the `[FromBody]` attribute.

```
[HttpPost]
public IActionResult Create([FromBody] Node node)
{
    //does stuff here
    return NoContent();
}
```

Comment: Ah, didn't know that, Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

If you are ever struggling with deserializing a body, try and do it manually to see if you are actually sending it correctly.

```
[HttpPost]
public void Post()
{
    string body = Request.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
}
```